# Adding "No Results" message when search returns no results

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I need some help adding a "No Results" message to pop up on the page below the search box if no results are found. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Current Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">  
Search: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="term" /><br />  
<br />
<button class="ladda-button btn btn-primary" data-style="zoom-in">Submit
</button>  
</form>  
<?php
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) 
    {
        $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM triadlocations WHERE address LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
    {  
    echo '<br /><br /> Location ID: ' .$row['locationid'];  
    echo '<br /> Address: ' .$row['address'];  
    echo '<br /> City: '.$row['city'];  
    echo '<br /> State: '.$row['state'];  
    echo '<br /> Zip: '.$row['zip'];
    }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: many simple solutions exist, like add a variable initialized to false and set it true in the while and check it afterwards OR put all rows in an array first and check if array is empty else loop.. and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the number of results before your `while` loop. Print the message if there are no results.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($r_query)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
    ...
    }
} else {
    echo "No Results";
}
```